# Google script, manipulate the number value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have one script behind one spreedsheet and I'm trying to export some cell values to document, and than email the pdv version of temp document..(trash it latter). I have problem with value I get or in the way I'm getting the value from spreedsheet to doc.. I can't manipulate the decimal point..

```
  // fix the price currency display and alignment in GOOGLE DOCUMENT TABLE!
  for (var i = 0; i < price.getNumRows(); i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < price.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++){
      var temp = price.getCell(i, j);
      temp.getChild(0).asParagraph().setSpacingAfter(0);
      if((j == 6 || j == 7) && !temp.getText() == "" ) {
        (i > 0) ? temp.replaceText(temp.getText(), temp.getText() + " kn") : void false; // skip the first line with header titles... 
        temp.getChild(0).asParagraph().setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
      }
    }
  }
```

after (i > 0) there is *temp.getText()* value.. that sometimes is like: 55,987654 and I would like that to round to two digits.. but can't :(

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found solution..

it's very simple but did take me some time.. hope that can help someone else with similar situation

```
parseFloat(temp.getText()).toFixed(2) + " kn")
```

this did the trick and the output is something like: 55,99 kn!